# How to suppress yfinance exception from getting printed in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, yfinance

```
import yfinance as yf,pandas as pd, numpy as np, os, sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
from pandas_datareader._utils import RemoteDataError

# Call yf.pdr_override() to override pandas_datareader's default behavior with yfinance.
yf.pdr_override()

data_incremental = pd.DataFrame()
stock='^NSEBANK'

try:
   data_incremental = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock, start=start_time, interval="1m")
except:
   pass
```

I am using above code to be called in a while loop with 20 seconds of sleep time in-between two calls.

Seems like above code should hide all exceptions thrown by yfinance but I still get below error which I want to suppress as it is cluttering the spyder console

Error Message:

```
ERROR:yfinance:
1 Failed download:
ERROR:yfinance:['^NSEBANK']: Exception('%ticker%: No price data found, symbol may be delisted (1m 2024-01-20 15:31:00+05:30 -> 2024-01-20 19:14:20+05:30)')
```

Comment: That's not an exception, that's a logging message.  If you don't want to see log messages from yfinance, adjust your log settings.